# Flutter Widget return type

Tags: flutter, dart

When building a method that returns a widget, is there any pros/cons to return the exact widget type if known, or can type of Widget always be returned?

```
Column _buildColumn() {
  return Column(
    children: [
       // children...
     ],
  );
}

Widget _buildAnotherColumn() {
    return Column(
      children: [
        // children...
      ],
    );
  }
```

Since it is know that we will return a `Column` in both cases, does the first, more exact return type make a difference?

Comment: There isn't really any objective downside, but there isn't really any objective upside either. A subjective downside might be that you would need to change the return type if in the future you need to change the UI returned by the method. A subjective upside might be transparency for what the method actually returns which will (maybe) aid in readability. For simplicity's sake, I'd argue there's no point in bothering, since Flutter doesn't care what a build method returns as long as it's a `Widget`.

Comment: @Abion47 thanks. Good point about readability, although I guess knowing it returns a Widget should be enough in most cases.